# Is there a way to schedule a render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a very long render and I was wondering if there is any way to make it only render at night so I can still use my computer during the day.

Edit: this is a single frame render, it will probably take upwards of 30 hours because it will be at 12k, 4096 samples, and has many polygons.

Comment: So you also want to pause and resume the render?

Comment: maybe you can use denoising and reduce the samples to save some time? I've found blender's denoiser to work very good on still frames

Comment: @Luciano that is the hope

Comment: @Jonas unfortunately with the scene I have denoising makes it really blotchy

Comment: Maybe you can use "Render region" (Ctrl+B when in camera view) to split your render into different parts, then combine the parts with any 2d editor. ?

Comment: Also, if you render with CPU (not GPU), your computer should still be very usable during rendering.

Comment: Hey :). There's an addon for pausing a render https://gumroad.com/l/bpupp. Costs two bucks, and works with Blender 2.8+.

Comment: @thibsert I can use my computer to watch Netflix and type, but I can't also play videogames

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks! I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Start to render when you go to bed?
If the render is not completely done in the morning, just continue from the last frame of the previous render session.

If that's not enough of an answer, please provide more info.

Comment: I have added more information in the post